# how parse json jquery/symfony

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, symfony

I have a input field for input a name of a city, and I would have the temperature with Openweathermap using Ajax jQuery, There is nothing that displays, if someone can help me,Thank you

controller:

```html
    /**
     *
     *
     * @Route("/meteo", name="weather_show")
     * 
     */
    public function meteoAction(Request $request)
    {
       if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            $ky=$this->container->getParameter('key');
            $vil=$request->query->get('ville');
            $tan=$vil.'&APPID='.$ky;
            $uri='http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='.$tan;
            $data=file_get_contents($uri);
             return new Response($data);
        }

        return new JsonResponse('no results found', Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    
    }
```

```html
        <label>City:</label>
  <input type="text"  id="chp">
  <p id="meteo"></p>
```

JSON:

```
{
    "coord": {
        "lon": 47.54,
        "lat": -18.91
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 802,
            "main": "Clouds",
            "description": "scattered clouds",
            "icon": "03d"
        }
    ],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 294.15,
        "pressure": 1021,
        "humidity": 52,
        "temp_min": 294.15,
        "temp_max": 294.15
    },

}
```

JS:

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#chp').keyup(function(){
    var $esp=$(this).val();
    $.ajax({
     type:'get',
     url:'{{path('weather_show')}}',
     dataType: 'json',
     data:{'ville':$esp},
     success:function(response){    
      $.each( $.parseJSON(response),function(i,value) {
        $('#meteo').html('value.temp');
        //alert('value.main');
       });          
     }
    });
   });
  });
 </script>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.html(value.main.temp);`?

Comment: `succes:function(response){` should be `success:function(response){` (missing an s in "success")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$.each(response,function(i,value) {
  $('#meteo').html('value.temp');
       
   });
```

instead of:
$.each( $.parseJSON(response),function(i,value) {
        $('#meteo').html('value.temp');

```
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks pretty good, try one of

```
$('#meteo').html(value.main.temp);
```

or

```
$('#meteo').innerHtml(value.main.temp);
```

instead of:

```
$('#meteo').html('value.temp');
```

Comment: Thank you,same result, nothing to display

Comment: Are you sure that the code is executing the success callback? Just saw a typo in your callback -- succes: needs to be success:

Also try using the native JSON.parse instead of the deprecated $.parseJSON to parse the response.